# Azure function called from API gateway management service return "internal Server error"

Tags: api, azure-functions, api-gateway

I have an azure function which runs perfectly fine in my local machine, I have deployed the azure function using function app in azure, when I directly call the azure function from function app , it works as well. But I am using Azure API management service to call the function from gateway. All the other functions are working fine , but I am getting an error for this new function I have written [image]

Comment: Check for the detailed error in Azure Portal.

- Go to the "Application Insight" associated with the Function app , then go to --> logs--> exceptions
- Go to the function app --> Advanced tool( Kudu) --> Debug Console --> LogFiles--> Application ( D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions) --> Select folders accordingly --> log file.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a function app and deployed that into our APIM in our local environment and we can able to deploy it successfully

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/Dfs7D5X.png)]

[image]

Try to follow the steps from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api) and regenerate the process again and also if you are trying to create APIM backend as per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/429873/calling-azure-function-from-apim-backend.html) you cannot call directly you need to create backend from APIM as shown below.

[image]

Also as [HariKrishnarajoli-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16630138/harikrishnarajoli-mt) mentioned you can check the error through application insight.